# jQuery success data is undefined (with context:this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS-Module and two functions. The first function should do the ajax request and call the second function of the module. Therefore I set the `context=this`.

```
return BaseController.extend(...) {
    ...
    loadChart: function() {
        ...
        $.ajax({
            url:...,
            data:....,
            async: false,
            context: this,
            success: function(data) {
                try {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                        // do something with data
                    }

                    this.function2();
                } catch() {
                    ....
                }
            }
        });
    },

    function2: function() {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

The call of `function2`works fine but `data`is undefined. Why?
If I delete the `context`statement my `data` is defined but I can't call `function2`... so what doing wrong? Thx.
I suppose I do not quite understand the scope yet ...

Comment: With respect, this must be observation error. Setting the `context` option has no effect whatsoever on what gets passed to the `success` function.

Comment: Try placing some console.log(this) around different parts of your code and you should be able to debug.

Comment: @FreemanLambda: I have. As said I can't use the data object so long as I use `context: this`. I don't know if it is related to "openUI5" Framework...

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like:

```
loadChart: function() {
    ...
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
        url:...,
        data:....,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            try {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    // do something with data
                }

                that.function2();
            } catch() {
                ....
            }
        }
    });
},

function2: function() {
    // do something...
}
```

}

Comment: here the context of your outer function is accessible by using the that variable. so you can use the both function, what you exactly want to do??